# Round to nearest, given tier

Tags: ms-access

**OBJECTIVE**

Develop a pricing model based off of CUSTOMERS' current DISCOUNTS. Note that the current CUSTOMERS' DISCOUNTS are not all the same (e.g Customer A receives a 25.25% discount while Customer B receives a 25.1238% discount).

**APPROACH**

1. Calculate a CUSTOMERS existing, weighted DISCOUNT *(completed)*
2. Create a DISCOUNT TABLE with ranges (e.g "Bronze Discount" = 0-15%,
   Silver = 15-25%, Gold = 25%-35%, etc..) *(completed)*
3. Place customers in the **nearest**(!!!) tier according to the DISCOUNT TABLE **(INCOMPLETE)**

**ISSUE**

I am having a hard time rounding someone to the nearest tier since the rounding variable (i.e "the nearest 10%") is actually changing - first tier = 15%, second tier = 10%, third tier = 25%.. Since the tier is changing, [Allen Browne's strategy](http://allenbrowne.com/round.html) does not suffice.

Please note that I am trying to push people to the NEAREST tier based off of their CURRENT DISCOUNT and the new DISCOUNT TABLE; simply checking whether or not someone falls between two table tiers is insufficient.

**EXAMPLE**

Table:
Bronze = 0-15%
Silver = 15-25%

Customer A, Existing Weighted Average Discount = 15.50%, New Calculated Tier = 25% (SILVER)
Customer B, Existing Weighted Average Discount = 14.95%, New Calculated Tier = 15% (BRONZE)

*In the aformentioned case, Customer A receives a huge discount when compared to Customer B, despite their existing weighted averages being close. Customer A's newly Calculated Tier is incorrect and should be placed into the Bronze Package.*

**QUESTION(S)**

1. How can I effectively place a customer in the nearest tier?

Comment: Is nearest really the appropriate word? That aside, since the ranges do not overlap, you should just be able to `.... C INNER JOIN DT ON C.currentDiscount >= DT.tierBegin AND C.currentDiscount < DT.tierEnd`. ...wait, Customer A should have been in Bronze? So, you're looking for nearest tier "ceiling"?

Comment: Correct - I am looking for customers to fall into the nearest tier, whether that tier be ABOVE or BELOW their current, existing discount

Comment: @Andre what indicated the tag need changed from `mysql` to `ms-access`?

Comment: @Uueerdo: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275170/stop-generic-database-questions-from-getting-mysql-as-a-suggested-tag), plus the reference to allenbrowne.com (a legendary site with Access tips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the higher percentage, as:

```
Bronze = 15
Silver = 25
Gold = 35
```

And then:

```
Select 
    Customers.*, 
    (Select Top 1 Discount.DiscountName
    From Discount 
    Order By Abs(Discount.Percentage - Customer.Discount) Asc) As CustomerDiscount
From Customers
```

Comment: Ended up converting your approach into an Excel format so that managers could easily manipulate the pricing tiers.

For those who are interested in the excel formula, please see: =INDEX(B1:B20,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A1:A20-C1)),ABS(A1:A20-C1),0)), taken from: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/finding-the-ultimate-closest-number-in-table/f9b4955d-6141-452b-83f2-747e5497a87d?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure of your exact table structure, something like this *might* work or be a good starting point.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID
, (SELECT DiscountID 
   FROM discounts AS d 
   ORDER BY ABS(d.ceiling-c.currentDiscount) ASC 
   LIMIT 1) AS nearestDiscountID
FROM customers AS c
```